# Fetch all url content for android webview asynchronously?

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, webview, synchronous

In the android web view the URL fetching is done synchronously causing a time lag.(`shouldInterceptRequest()` in webview client is called synchronously in a single IO thread, so resources will be loaded synchronously one after another)

I would like to know a way to make it asynchronous to avoid the above problem.

According to my research:

1. **Pre fetch the URLs and cache it** - *even if we pre fetch there is a time delay. (My application directly goes to the webview itself so i do not have sufficient time to pre fetch) And we do not know the URLs that the webview calls until we go through the shouldIntercept method in the web client.*
2. **Override shouldInterceptRequest()** to immediately return some fake result and start async load of the requested resource - *we do not know when the asynchronous call will end in order to refresh the webview with the resource.*